# Regular expression for location with slash at the end

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

I have location

```
location ~ /(apple|club|car|fly|fitness|nivea|nesquik) {
    alias /srv/static-pages/$1.html;

}
```

I tried

```
location ~ /(apple|club|car|fly|fitness|nivea|nesquik)(\/)* {
    alias /srv/static-pages/$1.html;

}
```

But it nothing gives me
Nginx gives me files accords uri, but i need work it with '/' at the end and without /
Example:
example.com/apple
example.com/apple/
Now i don't know how i can configure it
Help please

Comment: Which URL does not work?

Comment: You can try `location ~ ^/(apple|club|car|fly|fitness|nivea|nesquik)/?$ { ... }`

Comment: example.com/apple - works example.com/apple/ - doesnt work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What is the exact response?

Comment: when i try https://example.com/apple - response is 200, its give me apple.html file. So when i try with slash https://example.com/apple / - response is 404. I need that nginx gives me same response when i try request like https://example.com/apple